# Automating a Website Search and Download of hundreds of Files Using Python

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, python-requests, browser-automation

I am trying to automate a download process from a website for my data curation. It involves few searches and selecting the right file to download if the search term matches. Could you please  give mes some insights or Sample code to start with?

Flow chart of process will be like:

Go to website-->Click on Advanced Search>> Click on "Title" >>Select from few dropdowns and fix the search space---> Enter the search string --->select the correct one and download the latest release.

Comment: There's no magical lines of code that will read your mind and download what you want, it all depends on the website. Show us the site and show us what you want to scrape from it. The most help I can give on a post this vague is to look up the requests module and selenium.

Comment: the Steps are mentioned in my paragraph. I need to download data dumps based on geographies..I need to set the geographical location and select the drop downs and search my string. and finally download it if it matches

Comment: What's the website you're trying to do this on?

Comment: Fact  finder website

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want to do with the real values. What dropdown do you want to select, what search string do you want to use? What is the "correct one" you mentioned

Comment: Select" geography"---> Select geography Type as US-Stte-->Arizona-->close the search space-->in Topic enter SEX BY AGE if the exact match appears-->select lates version e.g 2014--> download it

Comment: Use Robot method, wherever there is windows download alert.